# How to make my terminal glow like this

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal, customization

I recently saw this terminal in a YouTube video... How can I customize mine to look like this?

[image]

Comment: I think he is using a theme. Maybe you can search "futuristic themes" or "glowing themes" for Ubuntu to find it.

Comment: Searched though... no good results... need more specific keyterms...

Comment: I can also tell that this the desktop environment in the screenshot is KDE so you can focus your search on KDE themes.

Answer (score 8):

At first, I thought it's achievable with glow effect for window decoration. But as I was going through the customization, it seems this look and feel is actually packaged as theme, though not as a full package.

Now, follow these steps:

### 1. Widget style

The widget on the theme is Oxygen. Go to the *System settings* → *Application style* → *Widget style* and choose *Oxygen* as the widget

### 2. Window decoration

Window decoration is the center for that glowing effect. But you don't need to create it, there is style already packaged. Go to the *System settings* → *Application style* → *Window decoration* and click on the **Get new decoration** button. Now on the search box, type *Ghost* and install the one needed. You can check the thumbnail.

Now select the newly installed decoration (Ghost Deco 2.2) and apply it.

### 3. Color scheme

Go to *System settings* → *Colour* and click on the **Get new scheme**. Type "Ghost" and install the one you prefer. There was a "Ghost cyan" (Which I liked) and original "Ghost color scheme". Now select the newly installed color and apply.

### 4. Desktop theme

Now the panel and widget theme in desktop. Go to *System settings* → *Workspace theme* → *Desktop theme* and click on the **Get new theme**. Search for the "Ghost" and install it, And apply.

### 5. Panel on the left

Now right click on the panel, click and hold the *Screen edge* button and move to the left. Adjust the width by selecting the *Width* button.

### 6. Icon theme

The icon theme was oxygen. If don't have that, install with `sudo apt install oxygen-icon-theme`. Then apply

### 7. Wallpaper

I didn't have a darkish scary wallpaper like that, but you can grab one from internet.

This should be able you to get the look you want.

Here is a screenshot from my experiment.

[image: kde theme customization]

Hope that helps!